# Automatic install of the backported version of the Android Photo Picker not playing nicely with Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest, photo-picker

I'm trying to implement the new [Android Photo Picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) but I'm running into an issue when trying to setup the automatic install of the backported photo picker module on older devices.

According to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#device-availability) we need to add the following to our app's manifest file to allow this:

```xml
<!-- Trigger Google Play services to install the backported photo picker module -->
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.metadata.ModuleDependencies"
         android:enabled="false"
         android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.metadata.MODULE_DEPENDENCIES" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="photopicker_activity:0:required" android:value="" />
</service>
```

However, when I do that, I get an error in Android Studio about "com.google.android.gms.metadata.ModuleDependencies" not being recognized or resolved.

[image]

How can we fix this?

Comment: If nothing else, you could try adding a dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-home`, version `16.0.0-beta1` or higher. Google's docs for [Matter integration](https://developers.home.google.com/matter/apis/home) show the same sort of `com.google.android.gms.metadata.MODULE_DEPENDENCIES` `<service>` element. If that works, you might then be able to identify the specific dependency that contains the class.

Comment: It seems some one logged an Issue : Track it here :  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279636992

Comment: I tried adding com.google.android.gms:play-services-home:16.0.0-beta1, it doesn't include com.google.android.gms.metadata.ModuleDependencies either.

Comment: have the same issue, any workarounds? is there an updated issue tracker link for this?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280659181 looks similar

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The docs weren't correct as reported in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280659181).

The recommendation is to add a `tools:ignore="MissingClass"` attribute
and to also suppress `AndroidDomInspection`:

```
<!--
    Prompt Google Play services to install the backported photo picker module
    https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#device-availability
-->
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.metadata.ModuleDependencies"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.metadata.MODULE_DEPENDENCIES" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="photopicker_activity:0:required" android:value="" />
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is solved by adding the following attribute: `tools:ignore="MissingClass"` to the XML node with the ModuleDependencies class. The documentation was updated: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#device-availability

Comment: Adding `tools:ignore="MissingClass"` does nothing for me. I'm still seeing `Unresolved package 'gms'`, `Unresolved package 'metadata' ` and `Unresolved class 'ModuleDependencies' `

Comment: That's just an IDE error right? It's because the class is does not exist. It does compile however.

Comment: We've always been able to compile with the IDE error. Adding that attribute does nothing